# problem with session registering?

Tags: php, session

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = $row[0]; //register session with user id
    header("Location: success.php");
}
```

`success.php:`

```
<?
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
    header("Location: view.php");
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

It doesn't seem to be working it keeps redirecting me to index.php like the session was never registered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add session_start(); to the first file as well.

Comment: Wow @eisberg that fixed it. Thank you so much! Post here so I can give you a green check mark? :)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a E_NOTICE error somewhere? Check your logs. You didn't provide enough code to debug this. There's nothing specific in this code that should cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add session_start() into first block

```
if ($count == 1) {
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = $row[0]; //register session with user id
    header("Location: view.php");
    exit;
}
```

And there is no sense in having success.php. Just send a user directly to view.php
where you have to verify user authentication again:

```
<?
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

and `exit` is obligatory after Location, or your protection will protect nothing

Comment: That's a good idea. I really don't need `success.php.` Thanks. I'll also make sure to also add exit; under all the header redirects.